# How to get linker errors at library compile-time in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker, shared-libraries

Consider an executable called `Exe`, which depends on a static library called `Lib1`, and `Lib1` depends on another static library called `Lib2`, so:

```
Exe -> Lib1 -> Lib2  (where '->' marks dependency)
```

Let's say I remove `Lib2` from `Lib1`'s additional library inclusions. In my experience, `Lib1` will still compile, but when I'll try to compile `Exe` (which is linked to `Lib1`), linker errors will occur stating that `Lib2` symbols are missing from `Lib1`.

Is there a way to "detect" unresolved symbols when compiling `Lib1` without needing to resort to compiling `Exe` to get notified of the unresolved symbols in the `Lib1`? If not, why?

Comment: Is `lib1` a DLL or a static library?

Comment: A static library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about static libraries, then there is no way of doing this. Static libraries do not link to each other. The linker looks for symbols it can't find in the executable in all the static libraries you list on the linker command line in turn. If it finds an unknown symbol in a static library, it then looks in the other static libraries, but the process is driven from the executable (or DLL) that you are linking.